# Pattern in Number of Conjugacy Classes of p-groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, conjectures, gap, p-groups

I was playing around with the number of conjugacy classes of $p$-groups in GAP and made the following conjecture:

> If there is a group of order $p^{2n}$ with $k$ conjugacy classes then there is a group of order $p^{2n+1}$ with $k+p-1$ conjugacy classes. The only exception is $p=2$, $n=2$, $k=7$.

For example, there are groups of order $64$ with $\{13,16,19,22,25,28,34,40,64\}$ many conjugacy classes so there are groups of order $128$ with $\{14,17,20,23,26,29,35,41,65\}$ many conjugacy classes.

Can someone prove this or find a counterexample?

---

For reference, here is the data that I was using.

[1]
[2]
[4]
[5.8]
[7.10,16]
[11,14,17,20,32]
[13,16,19,22,25,28,34,40,64]
[14,17,20,23,26,29,32,35,38,41,44,50,56,65,68,80,128]
[19,22,25,28,31,34,37,40,43,46,49,52,55,58,61,64,67,70,73,76,82,85,88,100,112,130,136,160,256]

[1]
[3]
[9]
[11,27]
[17,33,81]
[19,35,51,83,99,243]
[41,57,73,89,105,121,153,249,297,729]
[43,59,75,91,107,123,139,155,171,187,219,251,267,299,315,363,459,731,747,891,2187]

[1]
[5]
[25]
[29,125]
[49,145,625]
[53,149,245,629,725,3125]
[73,169,265,361,649,745,841,1225,3145,3625,15625]

[1]
[7]
[49]
[55,343]
[97,385,2401]
[103,391,679,2407,2695,16807]

```
n:=16;
l:=[];
for i in [1..NrSmallGroups(n)] do
    G:=SmallGroup(n,i);
    if not \in(NrConjugacyClasses(G),l) then 
        Add(l,NrConjugacyClasses(G));
        Sort(l);
    fi;
od;
Print(l);
```

---

One well-known pattern in the above data is a result of Hall that if $n=2k+e$ (with $e=0,1$) then $k=p^e+(p^2-1)(n+(p-1)t)$ for some $t\geq0$.
This explains why the above lists jump by $(2-1)(2^2-1)=3$ when $p=2$, by $(3-1)(3^2-1)=16$ when $p=3$, by $(5-1)(5^2-1)=96$ when $p=5$, and by $(7-1)(7^2-1)=288$ when $p=7$.

Comment: If you're interested in improving your code and further search in the GAP Small Groups Library, you may find the [GAP Carpentries-style lesson](https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/gap-lesson/) useful.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Thanks for the reference. It looks like my code was running out of memory on AllSmallGroups. I fixed this which allowed me to check the conjecture on $p=3$, $n=3$.

Comment: I think it would make sense not just to observe the number of classes but to see whether (some of) the groups are actually related. That is, do the groups with $k$ classes and with $k+p-1$ classes have common factor groups, and do they arise in nice ways in relation to these factor groups.

Comment: @ahulpke That's a good idea but it seems kind of hard to do. Sure, I can get GAP to tell me which id's correspond to groups of order $p^{2n}$ with $k$ classes and which id's correspond to groups of order $p^{2n+1}$ with $k+p-1$ classes, but how am I supposed to compare these abstract groups?

Comment: @ThomasBrowning look at the id numbers of factor groups. The hope is that there are common factors and thus the related groups arise in a regular way.

Comment: @ThomasBrowning you are welcome! By the way, you can write `if not NrConjugacyClasses(G) in l` (and furthermore, use `AddSet` instead of `Add` and `Sort`). The next step could be to make a function that takes `n` and returns `l`.